# How to shift table caption and number to be above and to the right of the caption?

Tags: tables, captions

[image]

I need what exactly highlighted in the picture. I am only using tabular at table envs with caption so my current table is:

```
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\caption{Optional components}
\begin{tabular}{|c|ccc|}
\hline
Хост & cuda 8 & cuda 10 & infiniband \\
\hline
cnode[1-7]      &  +          & -             & - \\
dnode[01-08]  &  -           &  +           & + \\
dnode[09-14]  &  -           & -             & + \\ 
control1          & -            & +            & + \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\label{tab:clus}
\end{table}
```

And I only get Table 1: Name...

Comment: Is the following closer to the desired output? https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPNqR.png

Comment: @leandriis, yes, only "optional components" must be centered while "Table ###" left at the right side. (yes, given name in the picture was quite long)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}

\DeclareCaptionFormat{hangright}{\rightline{#1}\\\centerline{\bfseries#3}}
\captionsetup[table]{format=hangright}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
  \centering
  \caption{Optional components}
  \begin{tabular}{|c|ccc|}
    \hline
        Хост     & cuda 8 & cuda 10 & infiniband \\ \hline
     cnode[1-7]  &   +    &    -    &     -      \\
    dnode[01-08] &   -    &    +    &     +      \\
    dnode[09-14] &   -    &    -    &     +      \\
      control1   &   -    &    +    &     +      \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \label{tab:clus}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]